# How to find data based on comma separated parameter in comma separated data in my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

We have below data,

```
plant table
----------------------------
| name  |  classification  |
|  A    |  1,4,7           |
|  B    |  2,3,7           |
|  C    |  3,4,9,8         |
|  D    |  1,5,6,9         |
```

Now from front end side, they will send multiple parameter like "4,9",
and the objective output should be like this

```
plant table
---------------------------
| name  |  classification |
|  A    |  1,4,7          |
|  C    |  3,4,9,8        |
|  D    |  1,5,6,9        |
```

Already tried with FIND_IN_SET code, but only able to fetch only with 1 parameter

```
select * from plant o where find_in_set('4',classification ) <> 0
```

Another solution is by doing multiple queries, for example if the parameter is "4,9" then we do loop the query two times with parameter 4 and 9, but actually that solution will consume so much resources since the data is around 10000+ rows and the parameter itself actually can be more than 5 params

If the table design is in bad practice then OK but we are unable to change it since the table is in third party

Any solution or any insight will be appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: currently is using mysql 5.7.24

Comment: What is maximal separate values amount in: `classification` column? provided criteria?

Comment: *Already tried with FIND_IN_SET code, but only able to fetch only with 1 parameter* What prevents `select * from plant where find_in_set('4',classification ) [and | or] find_in_set('9',classification )`?

Comment: @Akina classification can be more than 10, parameter can be more than 5 usually its around 5-15 params

Comment: @Akina actually multiple find_in_set is affecting the query speed since find_in_set is working without index, but yes that one also included in last hope solution..

Comment: I'm not interested in common, average and so on. I ask about maximal - i.e. the amount which will be exceed never. *multiple find_in_set is affecting the query speed since find_in_set is working without index* Your data have string type and you need to search a substring in any place of the value, index can be used never. Maybe, use not OR but UNION DISTINCT - this may be more fast, test.

Answer (score 2):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE broken_table (name CHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,classification VARCHAR(12));

INSERT INTO broken_table VALUES
('A','1,4,7'),
('B','2,3,7'),
('C','3,4,9,8'),
('D','1,5,6,9');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT DISTINCT x.name, x.classification FROM broken_table x JOIN cte
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(classification,',',n),',',-1) IN (4,9);
```

| name | classification |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,4,7 |
| C | 3,4,9,8 |
| D | 1,5,6,9 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oWCQuFYLBLVhWGpeKs4doT/1)

EDIT:

or, for older versions...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.name, x.classification FROM broken_table x JOIN 
(
  SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
) cte
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(classification,',',n),',',-1) IN (4,9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's just avoid the CSV altogether and fix your table design:

```
plant table
----------------------------
| name  |  classification  |
|  A    |  1               |
|  A    |  4               |
|  A    |  7               |
|  B    |  2               |
|  B    |  3               |
|  B    |  7               |
| ...   | ...              |
```

Now with this design, you may use the following statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM plant
WHERE classification IN (?);
```

To the `?` placeholder, you may bind your collection of values to match (e.g. `(4,9)`).

Comment: nb: we are unable to change the table design, out of our access.. but i am considering to create a mirror db VIEWS to split the CSV data to rows.. but maybe that one is the last solution .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want `or` so you can use regular expressions.  If everything were one digit:

```
where classification regexp replace('4,9', ',', '|')
```

However, this would match 42 and 19, which I'm guessing you do not want.  So, make this a little more complicated so you have comma delimiters:

```
where classification regexp concat('(,|^)', replace('4,9', ',', ',|,'), '(,|$)')
```